# How to ignore parameters in asp.net web api help page which are generated automatically from routing and from action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

One of my action parameters is instance of class which have param1, param2, param3 parameters (with [FromUri] attribute and I can't replace it with [FromBody]) 
And that parameters are in routing too.

When asp.net web api help page generates parameters from action I am getting duplicates of them in URI parameters. 
How can I ignore one of them?

Comment: You just remove it from the signature?

Comment: I can't because other cases will not work... I think it will be an attribute or configuration but researches and posts in blogs do not help

Answer (score 0):

In `Areas\HelpPage\HelpPageConfigurationExtensions.cs` find the method `GenerateUriParameters` and comment out the else clause.

```
else
{
    Debug.Assert(parameterDescriptor == null);

    // If parameterDescriptor is null, this is an undeclared route parameter which only occurs
    // when source is FromUri. Ignored in request model and among resource parameters but listed
    // as a simple string here.
    ModelDescription modelDescription = modelGenerator.GetOrCreateModelDescription(typeof(string));
    AddParameterDescription(apiModel, apiParameter, modelDescription);
}
```

Note that this might remove too many parameters from your help pages if you don't consistently use `[FromUri]`